# PHP/MYSQL - Generate only one random word inside for loop

Tags: php, mysql, random

I am making a small interraction between a user and the computer in a game. The user is always the first one to make a move, where he inputs a word of his choise.
I did a sql query that gets all plays made by the user while he is playing (maximun of 10 attempts). Once the user makes the first move I want the computer to generate a random word, like this:

```
$sql="Select word from plays where user=1 and id=$id";
$result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);

for($i=0;$i<10 && ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) ;$i++){

    // some code here

    $random="select word from words order by Rand() LIMIT 1";
    $result=mysqli_query($link, $random);
    $wrandom=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $wordR=$wrandom['word']; 
 }
```

In the first attempt all works correctly, a random word is generated but in the second attempt two random words are generated (instead of just one), in the third attempt, 3 words are generated and so on...
What should I do to generate just one random word per attempt?

Comment: Are you really using the same `$result` variable for both queries, or did you change that when copying the code?

Comment: I don't see anything here that will generate more words each time. I suspect the problem is in the `// some code here`.

Answer (score 1):

You can join your two queries into a single query.

```
$sql = "SELECT p.word as user_word, w.word as computer_word
        FROM plays AS p
        CROSS JOIN words AS w
        WHERE p.user = 1 AND p.id = $id
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $wordU = $row['user_word'];
    $wordR = $row['computer_word'];
    // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change the name of your variable `$result` in the loop because it creates a conflict with your first `$result` variable.

Comment: That seems to be the solution to a different problem. I don't see how this error would cause him to get more than one word on each iteration.